# Can I hide all server / os info?

Tags: nginx, ubuntu

I don't want anyone to be able to detect that I'm using NGINX or even Ubuntu from the internet. There are tools out there (such as BuiltWith) which scan servers to detect what tools they're using. Also, some cracking tools might help with deteting. What's the best / closest to that I can get to hiding all this info from the outside?

Answer (score 181, accepted):

You can stop it outputting the version of Nginx and OS by adding

```
server_tokens off;
```

to a `http`, `server`, or `location` context.

Or if you want to remove the Server header completely, you need to compile Nginx with the Headers More module in, as the header is hard coded in the Nginx source, and this module allows changing any http headers.

```
 more_clear_headers Server;
```

However, there are many hidden ways servers perform by accident via their implementation which may help identify the system. e.g. How it responds to a bad SSL request. I don't see a practical way of preventing this.

Some of the things I might suggest:

- change error templates
- block all ports except the services needed

Comment: Agreed. Look at nmap's OS detection for instance - this looks at the target hosts's responses to IP/TCP requests and is able to determine the OS that way. It's really not worth putting effort into this.

Comment: +1 on ErikA's advice. Better to secure your server as best as you can rather than relying on security through obscurity.

Comment: Server tokens only turn off the version number. Nginx does not allow for completely removing the header.

Comment: disregarding important security factors like "no version numbers" and probably even "no server vendor name" entirely is just ... a beginners mistake. **Of course** security through obscurity does nothing for your security itself **but** it sure as hell will at least protect against the most mundane, simplistic attack vectors - security through obscurity is a **necessary** step, it may be the first one and should **never** be the last security measurement -skipping it completely is a _very_ bad mistake, even the most secure webservers can be cracked if a version-specific attack vector is known.

Comment: There is a still an annoying server name "Nginx" returned in the body of a 301 redirect response and found no way to avoid that so far, the rule to use a custom html template does not work for 301.

Comment: This is helpful:  https://nmap.org/misc/defeat-nmap-osdetect.html#IPPERSONALITY

Comment: @specializt that is a most excellent comment!

Comment: No need to re-compile nginx with the "Headers More module", just install the needed package e.g with `apt install libnginx-mod-http-headers-more-filter`

Comment: Current documentation of "server_tokens" you can find here: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server_tokens

Answer (score 57):

If you have installed nginx using apt-get in Debian or Ubuntu, you might need to install the package nginx-extras to set or clear "Server" header

Once this is done, you can add the lines below in nginx.conf (usually /etc/nginx/nginx.conf):

To clear the "Server" header altogether:

```
more_clear_headers Server;
```

To Set a custom string as "Server"

```
more_set_headers 'Server: some-string-here';
```

Comment: Confirmed `more_clear_headers Server;` works as well on Debian Jessie 8.5 nginx version: nginx/1.6.2

Comment: This answer needs more upvotes. Although perhaps it should be noted that the directive needs to be placed inside the http block of the conf file (I think)

Comment: This works in `http`, `server`, `location`, and `location if` contexts. Source: [ngx_headers_more documentation](https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module#more_clear_headers)

Comment: For ubuntu users:

`sudo apt-get install nginx-extras`

and then set the headers

Comment: For me this failed with `unknown directive "more_set_headers"`. Solved it via enabling the module explicitly in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`. Simply add  `load_module modules/ngx_http_headers_more_filter_module.so;` at the beginning of the config file.

Comment: `nginx-extras` installs a lot of extra extras. If you only need to overwrite the Server header then you can also simply only install `sudo apt-get install libnginx-mod-http-headers-more-filter`

Answer (score 25):

@Martin F. Yes it does. You will have to compile it from source and change what's needed before compiling the source.

I assume you downloaded the last stable version you decompressed it and you know where the files are. If that's the case, do the following:

```
nano src/http/ngx_http_header_filter_module.c
```

Then look for line 48 if I recall correctly.

```
static char ngx_http_server_string[] = "Server: nginx" CRLF;
```

Replace nginx with MyWhateverServerNameIWant e.g.

```
static char ngx_http_server_string[] = "Server: MyWhateverServerNameIWant" CRLF;
```

Then

```
nano src/core/nginx.h
```

look for the line

```
#define NGINX_VER          "nginx/" NGINX_VERSION
```

change "nginx/" to "MyWhateverServerNameIWant/" so it will read

```
#define NGINX_VER          "MyWhateverServerNameIWant" NGINX_VERSION
```

Finally if you want also change the version number

look for the line
    #define NGINX_VERSION      "1.0.4"

and change "1.0.4" for whatever version you want. For example it will read

```
#define NGINX_VERSION      "5.5.5"
```

Hope it helps. Nevertheless. Securing a server goes far beyond not showing what's running. 
PHP is by nature insecure, and so is linux. Off course linux can be pretty secure if all needed measures are taken in order to achieve a decent security. As far as PHP is concerned I would recommend using [Suoshin](https://suhosin.org/) to help harden the security of your code.

Comment: +1, thanks. I'm leaving @Andy's as the official, just due to the easier approach, but this is excellent information.

Comment: I think you mean Suhosin.

Answer (score 15):

1) Install `nginx-extras` package alongside `nginx`:

```sh
apt install nginx-extras
```

2) Open `nginx.conf` and add following lines inside `http` block:

```
more_clear_headers Server;
server_tokens off;
```

[image: remove nginx server header]

3) Restart `nginx`

Answer (score 7):

After a lot of time working out how to do a custom flavor of nginx on ubuntu I realized you can use the lua module for this.

On ubuntu 14.04 if you install the `nginx-extras` package you can remove the server header by using:

`header_filter_by_lua 'ngx.header["server"] = nil';`

Throw this in the http block and every request will be lacking a `Server` header.

If it doesn't work run `nginx -V` to verify that you have the lua module compiled into your copy of nginx. If not, there is likely an alternate package you can use to get it.

Comment: Confirmed this works on Debian Jessie 8.5 nginx version: nginx/1.6.2

Comment: On debian testing this doesn't seem to work BUT installing `nginx-extra` made `more_set_headers "Server: whatever";` work, so +1 :D

Comment: You only need LUA enabled for this to work. Tnx

Answer (score 7):

Instead of the **header_filter_by_lua** it is recommended to use the new directive **header_filter_by_lua_block** which inlines the Lua source directly between curly braces (`{}`). With this it is not needed to escape special characters.

`header_filter_by_lua_block {
     ngx.header["server"] = nil
}`

https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#header_filter_by_lua_block

Answer (score 7):

Just want to point out that even though the server header is removed from response, the name of the server (nginx or openresty e.g.) is still clearly visible in the html error response that the server sends in case of an error.

Anyone can very easily get this response by e.g. sending a header that is too long. Nginx will return a 400 Bad Request, that does not contain a server header (if fixed), but the html itself will show it:

[image: Nginx error]

P.S. I don't know how to get rid of this one as well, really the html itself will give it away, so there should be a way perhaps to not generate these at all?

Comment: Use the `error_page` directive for all the errors you want to customize. For instance, `error_page 400 /err/400` will serve whatever's at `/err/400` in place of the default response.

Comment: [nginx `error_page` docs](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page)

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost: 
Why using an extra module as Headers More Nginx? Only to hide the server header. If a few lines, simple patch can reach the same solution for you.

As using an extra module could result in instability (how well has it been tested with your environment? With your other modules etc.) or insecurity (is this module regularly updated with bug and/or security related fixes?)

Secondly. 
This thread describes as reply 279389 how you can adjust the Nginx code to change the server header.
Problem is that they have forgotten HTTP/2. In short, nothing will change.
The server header will still be visible.

Less is more is better.
Ok I admit, I have also been looking for a good solution for a long time.
But finally found:

[**Nginx server header removal patch**](https://community.centminmod.com/threads/patch-nginx-server-header-removal.14976/)

I am finally redeemed from that annoying Nginx server header.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by **rapstacke** in the comments, `nginx-extras` installs a lot extra stuff (surprise). In addition to that, I found out that after installing nginx-extras, nginx would fail to restart after executing `systemctl reload nginx` a couple of times.

If you only want to remove the server header, you should install *libnginx-mod-http-headers-more-filter:*

```
sudo apt-get install libnginx-mod-http-headers-more-filter
```

This works for me without any problems on Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

Run this bash function in nginx source code folder. In nginx-$version, not in src/.

Based [on this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/279389/382998).

```
hidengxver () {
read -r -p "Your own http_server_string for safety: " http_server_string
first_string="static char ngx_http_server_string\[\] = \"Server: nginx\" CRLF;"
second_string="static char ngx_http_server_string\[\] = \"$http_server_string\" CRLF;"
sed -ire "s/$first_string/$second_string/g" src/http/ngx_http_header_filter_module.c

read -r -p "Your own NGINX_VER const: " nginx_ver
third_string="\#define NGINX\_VER          \"nginx\/\" NGINX\_VERSION"
forth_string="\#define NGINX\_VER          \"$nginx_ver\" NGINX\_VERSION"
sed -ire "s/$third_string/$forth_string/g" src/core/nginx.h

real_nginx_version=$( grep '#define NGINX_VERSION' src/core/nginx.h | gawk -F'"' '{print $2}' )
read -r -p "Your own NGINX_VERSION const: " new_nginx_version
fifth_string="\#define NGINX\_VERSION      \"$real_nginx_version\""
sixth_string="\#define NGINX\_VERSION      \"$new_nginx_version\""
sed -ire "s/$fifth_string/$sixth_string/g" src/core/nginx.h
}
```

Comment: Hi, Can you share detailed steps to make this change and build nginx

Answer (score 0):

Use below methods in source;  to eliminate nginx string from error messages

```
sed -i 's@"nginx/"@"-/"@g' src/core/nginx.h
sed -i 's@r->headers_out.server == NULL@0@g' src/http/ngx_http_header_filter_module.c
sed -i 's@r->headers_out.server == NULL@0@g' src/http/v2/ngx_http_v2_filter_module.c
sed -i 's@<hr><center>nginx</center>@@g' src/http/ngx_http_special_response.c
```

**then re-compile**

Answer (score -1):

Nginx-extra package is deprecated now.

The following therefore did **not** work for me as I tried installing various packages:

```
more_set_headers 'Server: My Very Own Server';
```

You can just do the following and no server or version information will be sent back

```
server_tokens '';
```

If you just want to remove the version number this works:

```
server_tokens off;
```

Comment: This appears to be available on _commercial version only_ since 1.9.13 - http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server_tokens

Comment: I can confirm, that empty string (`""` or `''`) is an invalid value for `server_tokens` directive even for (community) nginx version `1.15.7`

Comment: Based on https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server_tokens, only commercial subscription can set empty string disables the emission of the “Server” field