# How to disable server and server tokens header parameters on nginx

Tags: linux, nginx, ubuntu-12.04

I have a ubuntu server which has nginx 1.12.0 installed and i want to completely remove the server Response header

```
Server:nginx
```

If i install nginx-extras it will install the nginx/1.1.19 version and it will also disable the Etags,Are there any other options to remove the server header

Comment: This is utterly harmless. There is little point to removing it.

Comment: Duplicate: https://serverfault.com/questions/214242/can-i-hide-all-server-os-info

Answer (score 1):

Add this `server_tokens off;` on your `nginx.conf` under server section.

This will remove the `Server: nginx 1.12.0` server header

**Update:**

You need to compile it from source. Here's the [link](http://do.co/1peoY8M) I got from DO.

Download the nginx package then follow this steps:

```
cd ~/src/nginx/
vi +49 src/http/ngx_http_header_filter_module.c
```

Find the lines:

```
static char ngx_http_server_string[] = "Server: nginx" CRLF;
static char ngx_http_server_full_string[] = "Server: " NGINX_VER CRLF;
```

Modify to:

```
static char ngx_http_server_string[] = "Server: custom-server-name" CRLF;
static char ngx_http_server_full_string[] = "Server: custom-server-name" CRLF;
```

This

Comment: That will remove the server version but it will  still print Server: nginx but my requirement is to completely remove server header

Comment: I will just edit my answer above on how you can fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to have commercial subscription to nginx in order to remove nginx from your response body using server tokens 'string'