# Change server header on all endpoints (Flask + Nginx + Gunicorn)

Tags: nginx, http-headers, gunicorn, flask

I'm working on a Flask app that uses gunicorn and nginx and should hide its server header, so I managed to do it only for the homepage, like this:

`gunicorn.conf.py`

```
import gunicorn
gunicorn.SERVER = '.'
```

`nginx.conf`

```
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http{

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    # include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server{

        #server_tokens off;
        proxy_pass_header Server; # get server from gunicorn

     

        # let the browsers know that we only accept HTTPS
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=2592000;
        
        listen 80;

        add_header Content-Security-Policy $CSPheader;
        gzip on;



        location / {

            proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:5000
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            
            client_max_body_size 5M;

        }

        location /static/ {
            
            alias /home/app/static/;
            proxy_set_header Cookie $http_cookie;

            add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;


        }

    }
}
```

So, in my "/" page I'm getting

[image]

But elsewhere I'm displaying my server:

[image]

I'm not sure about how communication between nginx and gunicorn works, but I seem to be having a similar problem to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51138814/nginx-not-returning-cache-control-header-from-upstream-gunicorn), but I'm not sure how to use this information.

Any help to actually hide my server header would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate to https://serverfault.com/questions/214242/can-i-hide-all-server-os-info